# Web application - silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Is is reasonable to make a web application using Silverlight technology?
All elements on the page do this with Silverlight applications? (LOGIN, Chat, Search Users, etc.)
The application for a thousand users? 
What are the disadvantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number one disadvantage of Silverlight is that it requires browser support to run.  So if your goal is to build a truly cross platform solution that needs to work in many Browsers, be very careful.  For example, [Mobile Safari has no support for it](http://www.theipadguide.com/faq/does-ipad-supportplay-microsoft-silverlight).

My company made the mistake of choosing Silverlight early and then had to redo much of the development because Silverlight does not work on iPad.

Also Microsoft might be [dropping support for Silverlight in favor of WinRT](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/09/build-2011-what-is-winrt-and-i.php).

On the plus side, if you already have WPF knowledge, you should have little problem moving into Silverlight.  The development enviroment, tools and libraries are all top knotch and fun to work with.

Ultimately it all comes down to what you already know and what your requirements are.  If your target environment is always going to be Windows and you already know .net or WPF, going with Silverlight makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight works really well for big applications.

Silverlight has all the ingredients for a web application.

One disadvantage I can think of is that Linux users might not be able to view your application, because the Silverlight client for Linux is less feature-rich.

Comment: I don't think that many people develop applications with 1.42% of users in mind.

Comment: If your business runs on linux (there are some)

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember the biggest disadvantage would be if Microsoft drops support for Silverlight: [Microsoft may halt development work on Silverlight plugin after next release](http://www.theverge.com/2011/11/9/2548975/microsoft-may-halt-development-work-on-silverlight-after-next-release)